# Segmentation fault(core dump) when trying to read a float into a linkedlist in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I keep getting a segmentation fault(core dump) when I run addRecord() exactly after I type the float. There might be something terribly wrong with my use of pointers in the function but I can't seem to find what the problem is. This is from a project I am doing for school. Don't worry, the deadline has already passed. I just want to learn what's wrong because it's driving me crazy. Someone please help.

```
struct employee{
    double salary;
    string name;
    student* next;
};
struct linkedlist{
    employee *head=NULL;
    employee *tail=NULL;
};
struct linkedlist list;
void addRecord(){
    string name;
    cout << "Type the name of the employee:";
    cin >> name;
    float salary;
    cout << "Type the final average of the employee:";
    cin >> salary;

    struct employee *newOne;
    struct employee *head=list.head;
    newOne->name=name;
    newOne->salary=salary;
    newOne->next=NULL;
    if(list.head==NULL && list.tail==NULL){
        list.head=newOne;
        list.tail=newOne;
    }
    else{
        newOne->next = head;
        list.head=newOne;
    }
}
```

Comment: `newOne` is not initialized. So accessing `name` or other data member in that is undefined behavior. You need to assign a valid value or use `new employee()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment says, you'll want to change the line:

```
    struct employee *newOne;
```

to actually creating a new employee:

```
    struct employee *newOne = new employee();
```

otherwise the pointer won't actually point to a real employee struct and it'll crash.